# The file "phinx.yml" does not exist

Tags: php, phinx

I setup phinx using the --format php during the init.  It is in the /config/database folder as database.php  Whenever I try to run the migration I get the following error.

The file "phinx.yml" does not exist.

I'm now using a .yml file.

My phinx.php is in my root and looks like this

```
<?php

return
[
    'paths' => [
        'migrations' => './database/migrations',
        'seeds' => './database/seeds'
    ],
    'environments' => [
        'default_migration_table' => 'phinxlog',
        'default_database' => env('DB_ENV'),
        'production' => [
            'adapter' => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'name' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'user' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'pass' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'table_prefix' => ''
        ],
        'development' => [
            'adapter' => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'name' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'user' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'pass' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'table_prefix' => ''
        ]
    ],
    'version_order' => 'creation'
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The config file should be in the same directory that you are running `phinx` from.

Generally this would be the root of your project, rather than `/config/database` folder.

You can either move it to the root, or you can point `phinx` to the file using the `--configuration` option:

```sh
./vendor/bin/phinx migrate --configuration config/database/phinx.php
```

Comment: and what if the same error message comes up for seeding?

Comment: ```php vendor/bin/phinx seed:run -s RoleSeeder```
I don't have any yml file, instead I've got a config/migrations.php for configurations